# .Net Core Multiple Startups files and service implementations for different api versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want two versions of api gateway (1.0 and 2.0) in Net Core 3.1 . Additionally, I have a cache  and permissions service. Is it possible for version 1.0 to have a different permissions service implementation than for version 2.0? Is it possible to have two different Startup files?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we could have Startup class conventions and Startup method conventions.

[Startup class conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#startup-class-conventions):

The app can define multiple Startup classes for different environments. The appropriate Startup class is selected at runtime. The class whose name suffix matches the current environment is prioritized. If a matching Startup{EnvironmentName} class isn't found, the Startup class is used.

That means you could have multiple startup.cs like StartupDevelopment,StartupProduction, Startup. If your host application's server environment variable "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" has been set to the `"Development"`, it will use StartupDevelopment. If there is no startup.cs match the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`, it will use default Startup.cs.

More details about how to set the environment variable , you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-environment).

Codes like below:

```
public class StartupDevelopment
{
    public StartupDevelopment(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}

public class StartupProduction
{
    public StartupProduction(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tested this solution yet, but in the future I probably will. 
Can I have two Startup class instances for the development environment? One for api version 1.0 and second for version 2.0?

Comment: No, each environment could only run one startup class. We couldn't run multiple startup class at same environment. But you could create a apione environment and apitwo environment for each startup.cs calss.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to register two different service implementations, with two different interface types.

```cs
interface IPermissions {}
interface IPermissionsV2 : IPermissions {}

class PermissionsV1 : IPermissions {}
class PermissionsV2 : IPermissionsV2 {}

public class APIV1{
    public APIV1(IPermissions ...){}
}
public class APIV2{
    public APIV2(IPermissionsV2 ...){}
}
// etc
```

Though you *could* use a proxy service to locate the real service. This feels like an anti-pattern that I shouldn't recommend;

```cs
interface IPermissions {}
interface IPermissions<T>:IPermissions {}

public class PermissionsV1 : IPermissions {}
public class PermissionsV2 : IPermissions {}

public class PermissionsProxy : IPermissions<T>{
    private IPermissions implementation;
    public PermissionsProxy (IServiceProvider provider){
        if (typeof(T) ... )
            implementation = provider.GetService<PermissionsV1>();
        // etc
    }
    public void Method() => implementation.Method();
}

public class APIV1{
    public APIV1(IPermissions<APIV1> ...){}
}
public class APIV2{
    public APIV2(IPermissions<APIV2> ...){}
}
```

Or configure [multiple middleware pipelines](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/04/running-multiple-independent-asp-net-core-pipelines-side-by-side-in-the-same-application/) with different services. But that feels over-complicated.

Comment: I wanted to avoid two implementations of one service, but I see that otherwise it is impossible. Startup files for different environments is also a good idea. Brando Zhang and Jeremy Lakeman thank you very much for your help.